# Get Payload JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, controller, jwt

I work with springboot and use oath2 (JWT).
My token is the next

[token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5D3G.png)

I want to get the payload from a controller or a filter but i dont know how.

I try this but it doesn't work

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public String getB(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt principal, @RequestHeader("refresh") String refresh) {

    System.out.println(principal.getClaims());;
    
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();        
    Object details = authentication.getDetails();        
    
    
    if ( details instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationDetails ){
        OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oAuth2AuthenticationDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)details;
        Map<String, Object> decodedDetails = (Map<String, Object>)oAuth2AuthenticationDetails.getDecodedDetails();

        System.out.println( decodedDetails.get("time_created") );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Framework - Where to parse JWT for custom claim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231203/spring-framework-where-to-parse-jwt-for-custom-claim)

Comment: You have the Jwt object as input, which is the thing you should use, but you do not use it.

Comment: Yes Allesandro, thank

Answer (score 0):

(SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH)
I can get a details with the next code:

1. get access token
2. decode this token
3. add decode token in a map
4. get detail that i need by key in the map

```
   @GetMapping("/user")
    public String getB(OAuth2Authentication auth) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

        final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
        // token
        String accessToken = details.getTokenValue();
        System.out.println(accessToken);

        JsonParser parser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
        Map<String, ?> tokenData = parser.parseMap(JwtHelper.decode(accessToken).getClaims());
    
        String customField = (String) tokenData.get("time_created");
```